# Windows 10 - Compile C++ in cmd

Tags: c++, cmd, compilation

I have a `main.cpp` file in my `C:\Documents` folder. What is the command that I need to type in order to compile this program in C++11?

And also, is there a way to include options like `-Wall`, `-Wextra`, or `-Werror`, similar to how you can do so in Ubuntu?

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: There are so many different ways you could do this, and this all depends on your compiler. Personally, I would recommend either visual studio (since it does all that noise for you) or GCC

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have GCC:

1. Go to the Start and type `command prompt`.  Once the option is displayed, make sure that you right click it, and run it as an administrator.  You need admin rights, in order to run the `.exe` file that is generated after compilation.
2. Once `command prompt` (`cmd`) opens, navigate to the `Documents` folder, since that is where your Main.cpp file is.
3. Then type:

   ```
   g++ -std=c++11 -Wall Main.cpp -o Main.exe
   ```
4. This will create a file named `Main.exe` in your `Documents` folder.  Since you have admin rights, you can simply run:

   ```
   Main.exe
   ```

Sample screen shot below:

[image: Compilation Screen Shot]

You can find detailed options about compilation [**here**](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/mingw_for_first_time_users_howto).

Comment: Thank you so much, very helpful answer!