# Installing / Running "Hello World" in C++ with Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I'm having a problem with C++. Specifically, I am just trying to start out and well I am having little to no luck. So far I have downloaded and tried two compilers. I've tried to use:

1. Clang - I've tried to install it and it failed to install. I got two
   error messages when I tried that:

   1. `Failed to find MSBuild toolsets directory`
   2. `Failed to open files while installing`
2. Then I tried to install Dev C++ and had a bit more luck, yet still
   ran into problems. I just couldn't get the "Hello World!" file to
   compile and run. I got the following error messages with that:

   ```
    [linker error] undefined reference to '__dyn_tls_init_callback'

     [linker error] undefined reference to '__cpu_features_init'

      [linker error] undefined reference to '__setargv'
   ```

Comment: If you are a student, open-source, or individual developer, then here is [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/post-download-vs/?sku=community&clcid=0x409&downloadrename=true) and [how to create a console application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46e82t5z.aspx).

Comment: Here is an answer about *running* C++ using g++: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37371163/2172854

Comment: Windows is a niche OS only if you try to use Linux tools that are not properly adapted. The native Windows compilers come with [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) that is fully setup using a single install program. And specifically designed for use on Windows.

Comment: They do communicate this in plain English for me, it's just that it takes some effort when things change between book versions. Which I think is what happened here. Also, as said above, using Linux tools in Windows is somewhat harder than using native VS Community as it is a single click install with just some minor configuration.

Comment: Ah I see. Great responses.

Anyhow, I've tried to locate Visual Studio for XP after all these failed attempts at configuring the open source compilers and I haven't been able to find it.

My next bet is to read the documentation of these open source programs or download Linux!

Any other suggestions? You know, as far as trying to configure these programs for XP, or finding Visual Studio? or in the event that I download Linux, any tips on that?

Thanks!

Comment: XP is obsolete, so no, you're not going to find much up-to-date software or tutorials for it.  I personally prefer Windows, but if you aren't able to update to a supported version, Linux is probably your better bet.  FWIW, I'm running [Linux Mint](https://www.linuxmint.com) on an old laptop and found it relatively painless.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different compilers and other tools that can be used for developing and debugging. Setting up a development environment can be a challenge especially if you are learning.

An IDE - Integrated Development Environment consists of an editor, a build tool, compiler and linker, debugger and probably more tools. Compiler takes your code + system header files and produces object files. Linker takes object files + system lib files and produces executable.

You need to get a C++ IDE installed and working so you can learn some C++ without worrying too much (yet) about building compiling linking. But you will need to learn about each component!

I do not know of an IDE that comes with a very simple install! In the old days of TurboC++ and BorlandC we had it good, kindof! Google for https://www.google.ie/search?q=c%2B%2B+ide+for+windows Eclipse and Netbeans are big and need some setup (install language compilers and libs) before you get productive. But they are very popular. E.g. instructions steps to get up and running with Eclipse and C++ https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html

If you are learning can you start with an interpreted language like python first? Before diving into C++. Learning c before C++ might be a good idea.

Comment: That's an option! I'd really like to get this working because the book was pricey.

I have started to reopen my HTML&CSS book just to get my fingers moving on the keyboard in the meantime.Also tried to take a second crack at Python again ( I tried it a while ago with success but stopped), and I couldn't get that to work!


Really starting to consider downloading Linux!

Comment: Maybe do go for Eclipse then (or Netbeans, both work on Windows and Linux).  I think Netbeans recommends installing Cygwin and clang or other compilers and using those. If installing Cygwin you could start with adding g++ and then just hand-compiling and linking simple c++.

Comment: Actually maybe start very simple. Install cygwin with gcc/g++. Then hand compile and link single files very simple: 'g++ file.cpp -o file'. Multiple files 'g++ file1.cpp -c -o file1.obj' 'g++ file2.cpp -c -o file2.obj' 'ld file1.obj file2.obj -lc -l<otherlibs> -o file'